# Buttons in VBox overlap

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to add buttons to a `VBox` that is contained in a `BoarderPane` but they seem to overlap.
The `VBox` snippet from my fxml file is

```xml
<VBox fx:id="leftPlayerPlayArea" alignment="CENTER" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="120.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
    <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets left="30.0" />
    </BorderPane.margin>
    <opaqueInsets>
        <Insets />
    </opaqueInsets>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

When I add the buttons in my controller class, the buttons get nicely added to my Hbox but they don't get nicely added to my Vbox. Here are the images:

**VBox**

[image: This is an image of the Vbox]

**HBox**

[image: This is an image of the Hbox]

Lastly here is how I am creating these Buttons:

```
 private Button playerPromptButtonCreator(String buttonText, EventHandler<ActionEvent> event, int id) {
    Button button = createBtn(buttonText);
    button.setMinWidth(BTN_MAX_WIDTH);
    button.setMinHeight(BTN_MAX_HEIGHT);
    button.setOnAction(event);
    if (playerPositions.get(id) == PlayerPosition.LEFT){
        button.setRotate(90);
    }
    if (playerPositions.get(id) == PlayerPosition.RIGHT)
    {
        button.setRotate(270);
    }

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { //and create the button if it doesnt exist if it doesnt
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //THIS IS MY LINE
            playerPlayAreas.get(id).add(button);
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

I also tried `setSpacing()` property for my `VBox` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the size of a node in the parent layout JavaFX uses the bounds of the ***untransformed*** node, i.e. it does not consider the rotation and uses the size that is rendered as width as height.

You can fix this by wrapping the `Button` in a `Group` but this would require you to edit the signature of the method or modify the calling method:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Yes");
Button button2 = new Button("No");
button1.setRotate(90);
button2.setRotate(90);

VBox layout = new VBox(new Group(button1), new Group(button2));
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my problem, one more thing though what if I want my buttons to be spaced out but not my cards, because I also add cards to this section during game play. The buttons are prompt buttons I hide and show them throughout the game.